# Magento 2 Error while import bulk product image programmatically

Tags: magento-2.1, product, product-images

I am using magento 2.1.11. I am trying to fetch almost 4000 product with product image.Using below code.

```
$mediaDir = BP.'/pub/media/';
$tempcatimg = $mediaDir.'/tempcatimg';
$count = 0;                 
foreach($images as $image){
  $path = $this->saveImage($domain.$image->url , $image->id, $tempcatimg );
   if ($count == 0){
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $path , array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false ); 
    }else {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery( $path , null, true, false );
    }
}
```

Save function as below:

```
public function saveImage($img, $imgId, $mediaDir) 
{
    $imageFilename      = basename($img);    
    $image_type         = substr(strrchr($imageFilename,"."),1);
    $filename           = $imgId.'.'.$image_type;

    if (!file_exists($mediaDir)) mkdir($mediaDir, 0777, true);
    else chmod($mediaDir, 0777); 

    $filepath           = $mediaDir . '/'. $filename;
    if(@getimagesize($img)){
        $ggh=file_get_contents(trim($img));
        $fp = fopen($filepath, "w");
        fwrite($fp, $ggh);
        fclose($fp);
        return $filepath;
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

But getting error

> Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=14131 in
>   /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
>   on line 316

I have search for above error got this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753674/error-while-sending-query-packet)

I have increased **max_allowed_packet** to **512M**

But no luck every time getting error. If I comment addImageToMediaGallery code then all products are created.